# Is it possible to create parent dockerfile as I have multiple asp.net microservices project and each project have one dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, yaml, azure-aks

[example file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWSjq.png)
my project looks like this ,I have 6 projects ,I want to have single parent dockerfile which can call the other dockerfiles

I have multiple  docker files as

```
**-docker.users
-docker.owners
-docker.consumers
-docker.settings etc****
```

I want to have single parent docker file which can call the other docker files ,which needs to be deployed on Kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Docker Compose to manage and orchestrate multiple containers that each have their own Dockerfile. Using Docker Compose would be a good fit if your projects are meant to run as separate services, each in its own container.

1. For each of your projects (`users`, `owners`, `consumers`, `settings`, etc.), have an individual Dockerfile. For instance:

- `Dockerfile.users`
- `Dockerfile.owners`
- `Dockerfile.consumers`
- `Dockerfile.settings`

2. Create a `docker-compose.yml` file to define and run all of your services.

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  users:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.users
    ports:
      - "5001:80"
      
  owners:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.owners
    ports:
      - "5002:80"
  
  consumers:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.consumers
    ports:
      - "5003:80"

  settings:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.settings
    ports:
      - "5004:80"
```

3. Navigate to the directory containing your `docker-compose.yml` file and run:

```bash
docker-compose up --build
```

This will build and start all of your services as defined in the Docker Compose configuration.

4. Tools like [Kompose](https://kompose.io/) can convert a `docker-compose.yml` into Kubernetes manifests. Instead of using Kompose, you can also use [Helm](https://helm.sh/), a package manager for Kubernetes, which allows you to define, install, and upgrade even the most complex Kubernetes applications. With Helm, you can create a Helm chart for each of your services and deploy them to your Kubernetes cluster.